# CSS how to fix tfoot?

Tags: css, css-tables

I would like to fix tfoot in table. Below is code where I do try to display tbody in scroll ball and it works, but at now tfoot is displayed below thead.

```
tbody {
    display:block;
    height:350px;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 100%;
}


thead, tfoot, tbody tr {
    width:100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

thead, tfoot {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}
```

Comment: Is the tfoot in the markup also under the thead?

Comment: at now is displayed in the order: thead -> tfood -> tbody

Comment: and should thead -> tbody -> tfoot

Comment: Can you set a snippet with some of your html, to show live your issue ? as it is, it should work unless your markup is not what we would expect http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLbOpb

Comment: When I say in the markup, I mean in the html, in the source. Anyway, can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?